# Text label and color changes after transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[Link to Plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/eZmEXL66Y5zPxovdXf2h/preview)

What I have is two years of data and I want to plot a moving bubble chart
The problem I am getting is the label does not update after the transition
and it seems that there are some mismatches happening
Not sure how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Which label do you mean? I'm seeing the year label change to 2014 after the transition.

Comment: It is the data label that is wrong. For example, if you look at the blue circle (S), it becomes "A" after the transition which is incorrect. And the title label (the one you hover your mouse on), stays at 2013 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating the title value use below code:

**[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/463r6zMAheySaBscfica?p=preview)**

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("title")
                        .data(dataset)
            .text(function(d, i) { return d[0] + "\n" + "Year: " + d[1] + "\n" + "Defects: " + tooltipformatPercentage(d[2]) + "\n" + "Process Audits: " +  tooltipformatPercentage(d[3]) + "\n" + "FOB: " + d[4]; });
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj, it solves part of the problem. The other problem I have is that those circles do not have the same ID after clicking the play button. Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean that circle ID...?

Comment: I have found the problem. It's the sorting that mess up the data.